# Cloudflare Proxy with SSH tunnel to prevent IP address exposure

Tags: ssh, proxy, cloudflare

- If I disable the Cloudflare Proxy, I can SSH to my server, but my IP
  address is exposed to the world (see Cloudflare warning below).
- If I enable the Cloudflare Proxy, my IP address is hidden, but I can no
  longer SSH to my server.

Has anyone set this up successfully?

[image: Cloudflare Proxy Warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Cloudflare Proxy to protect an SSH endpoint, you should look at [Cloudflare Spectrum](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/products/cloudflare-spectrum/). Protection for SSH endpoints is available starting on a Pro plan. Setup is [documented here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/spectrum/getting-started).

Comment: Thanks, @Paolo Tagliaferri. Turns out I was not a paid plan.

Comment: SSH tunneling is now available on a free plan.